# The number of pending suggested edits is completely unreadable

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

There's a notification icon displaying the amount of pending suggested edits, but the number within is completely unreadable - looks like the font color is identical (or almost identical) to the color of the box surrounding it.

[image: There's an unsightly block that's the indicator. I bet you can't even tell there's a 2 in it.]

Comment: Dammit! I must see it! I must pixelate it! MUST PIXELATE EVERYTHING

Comment: @badp is it my fault you're so sloooooooooooooow in gaining rep? Get on it already!

Comment: I heard rumors that there was a number there, but I just figured it was supposed to be a square.

Comment: @Grace if you text-select it, you can see the number there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment.